# Target class [CrudsController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have created an controller having name `CrudsController.php` where I am performing crud operation and here is my route `web.php` file as mention below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', 'CrudsController@index')->name('employee.index');
```

But what happen when I run command `php artisan serve` then I got this message `Target class [CrudsController] does not exist.` I don't know why? Please help me to solve this.

Thank You

Comment: are you using Laravel 8?

Comment: yes @lagbox its 8.25

Comment: Can you post the CrudsController class? in what folder is the file?

Comment: project\app\Http\Controllers @GertB.

Comment: Check the namspace and classname

Comment: @GertB. now I have got `Route [users.store] not defined.`

Comment: @miz thats another error that has nothing to do with this question. it means that you link to a route... that is not defined...